# How to get the address literally allocated by allocaInstr in llvm?

Tags: memory-management, llvm, alloca

I am trying to do some instrumentation over an ll file. One of the task I want to achieve is the following.

Whenever I meet an AllocaInstr like:

```
%1 = alloca i32
```

I want to instrument a function `call __save_addr()` after it as follows:

```
%1 = alloca i32

call __save_addr(i32* %1)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Iterate over all the instructions in the function](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#iterating-over-the-instruction-in-a-function). For each one,
2. [check](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates) whether it's an `AllocaInst`. If it is,
3. [Create a new `CallInst`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1CallInst.html#a3ff9b8134737690083410aeeea42308e) calling your function*, and pass the `AllocaInst` instance as the first argument.

*If your function is already in the module, you can find it via [`Module::getFunction`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a3f156c68d0efa530f05698ca15d66593); if it's in another module, you'll have to create a declaration for it.