# In C++ LLVM Builder API, how can I get the address of a stack allocated variable?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have a stack allocated value, created via an `alloca` instruction, as a `Value* v`.

I want to write the C++ llvm builder code that will *assign the address of `v`, which lives on the stack, to a new variable `p`*.

That is, for the equivalent in C, if I have a local variable `v`, I want to get its address into `p`, like:

```
int c = 10;
int* p = &c;
```

I put some code into GodBolt, and I found out this is apparently the equivalent LLVM IR - so I want to produce IR like this:

```
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  %3 = alloca i32*, align 8
  store i32 %0, i32* %2, align 4
  store i32* %2, i32** %3, align 8, !dbg !18
  %4 = load i32*, i32** %3, align 8, !dbg !19
```

I should add that the above `llvm` IR doesn't make sense to me.  Why do we need the first store? It seems like a redundant copy of `%0` to `%2` to me. Why couldn't i take the address of `$0` directly? And in the second store, it looks like we're casting the value into a pointer top... Is that just a trick of the light, and that instruction actually means "please copy the address of %2" even though it doesn't say that directly? Is this actually the right IR that I want to generate? Is there a better way to write this?
Thanks, apologies for my ignorance of LLVM IR.

Possibly related questions:

- [How to get the address literally allocated by allocaInstr in llvm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506808/how-to-get-the-address-literally-allocated-by-allocainstr-in-llvm?rq=3)
- [Is there any way to know the stack address of stack allocated local variable created using alloca instruction in LLVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249973/is-there-any-way-to-know-the-stack-address-of-stack-allocated-local-variable-cre)

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Use Builder to create two `alloca`s, two `store`s and one `load` instruction.

Comment: The `alloca` instruction is the address you want, just like an `add` instruction is the result of the addition.

Comment: Thanks. @arrowd you're right: by the time I arrived at the IR above, I think I was close to the answer. But I don't exactly understand that IR itself, so I wasn't sure if that's even the right way to go about it. I've updated my question to clarify my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think just picking up the `llvm::Value` from the return of the `alloca` (which represents the register holding the address) is enough for further use  including assignments later on.

```cpp
  std::string x = "x";
  llvm::Value *alloca_x =
      builder.CreateAlloca(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(context), nullptr, x);

  llvm::Value *ten =
      llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(context), 10);
  llvm::Value *assign_x = builder.CreateStore(ten, alloca_x);

  std::string p = "p";
  llvm::Value *alloca_p =
      builder.CreateAlloca(llvm::Type::getInt32PtrTy(context), nullptr, p);

  llvm::Value *assign_p = builder.CreateStore(alloca_x, alloca_p);
```

A [more complete example](https://gist.github.com/jerinphilip/1d1e6674034e9e46089f6cff24a09ef9) generates the following for me:

```
  %x = alloca i32, align 4      ; x = alloca
  store i32 10, ptr %x, align 4 ; x := 10
  %p = alloca ptr, align 8      ; p = alloca
  store ptr %x, ptr %p, align 8 ; *p := &x
```